# Executing multiple commands from history in Vim

Tags: vim

I can access the command history in Vim with `q:`. I can execute any command from there simply placing the cursor on its line and pressing enter. **Is there a way to execute multiple commands at once?** I have tried to visually select the lines in the command history and then pressing enter, but that doesn't work. Many thanks.

Edit: In Vim, when you run a command from the command history window, it runs on the original window. This is the behaviour I am trying to achieve, but with multiple commands.

Answer (score 2):

After selecting the lines type colon followed by `:source` (also can be shortened as `so`) command.

Or type `:,+1so` to execute current line and the next one.

This works in any window provided that you have up-to-date version of Vim installed.

Upd. If you need to execute commands in the first window then copy text and drop out of the command window manually. Then execute lines copied into register. E.g. `y<c-c><c-c>:@"<enter>` See `:h :@`

Comment: This is interesting, thank you for the tip, but it doesn't do what I asked for. This runs the commands on the same window, so if I am in the command history (`q:`), the selected commands will run on the command history window, not in the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the command-line window and thus create new commands. You can concatenate commands using the bar operator `|` (see [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar) for reference and for limitations). You will also need to repeat the colon for the next command.

For example, given a command-line history such as

```
s/foo/bar/
s/bar/baz/
```

You can `A|:<Esc>J` to append `|:` and join the lines into

```
s/foo/bar/|: s/bar/baz/
```

Press `<CR>` and your newly created compound command will run.

Of course, you're not limited to joining lines. You can use Vim's full editing capabilities to create new commands from history.

In the above example, we could decide to take a short cut and turn "foo" into "baz" right away by deleting everything in between

```
s/foo/baz/
```